# Function scope chain - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding scope chain in javascript.
I have the following code:

```
var num = 10;
function addFunction(num){
    var fun = function(num2) {
        return num + num2;
    }
    num++;
    return fun;
}
console.log(addFunction(5)(5));
```

I am not sure why it will print 11 in the console.
can someone help me with that?
i thoug that it will print 15. though i'm having hard time to understand the scope of the function.

Thanks

Comment: `num` is a parameter of the `addFunction`, and is local to there. The `num` in the `fun` will refer to that (incremented) variable; the global `num` is shadowed.

Comment: var num = 10; doesnt effect function. and function call addFunction(5)(5) . ; / whats happend is : 1) first call addFunction(5) return fun and if num++ its mean 5++ = 6. -> 2) second call addFunction(5)(5) calling fun(5) { // and return 6+5}

Answer (score 2):

By what logic would it print 15? Ah, I see.

The line

```
var num = 10;
```

is irrelevant. Inside `addFunction` `num` is the parameter variable that is captured by the anonymous function assigned to `fun`. By the time `fun` was called, parameter `num` had been incremented by 1 and become 6.

Comment: though the function it self is being called in the global scope without any relation to addFunction that was used only for the creation of the function fun.

Comment: is it a question? Inside anonymous function, 'num' is the 'num' closest to the function code, which is the `num` parameter of `addFunction`.

Comment: @itzikos: Well, yes. That's how it works. The scope in which a function is called has *never* influenced the scope chain. The scope chain is fixed when the function is *created* .

Comment: @Igor: 116611 didn't last long, someone upvoted me :-( I better wait till 222222.

Answer (score 1):

about why you got console.log(addFunction(5)(5))  == 11 see my answer above.

And

if you want call console.log(addFunction(5)(5))  and get 10,  you can use this solutions:

```
//other solutin

function tickF(n) {

 var y = function(m) {
  return f(m+n);
 }, f = arguments.callee;
 y.toString = y.valueOf = function () {
  return n;
 };
 return y;
}

console.log('no memory leak', String(tickF(1)(2)(3)), String(tickF(1)(2)(3)))
```

answer 6, 6

or with closure, but this solutoin you cant call second time, cause total variable wasnt reset after call-chain complete:

```
//chain call fn()()()
var tick = (function(){
  var total = 0;
  function fnGenerator(arg) {
    total += arg;
    return  arguments.callee;
  }

  fnGenerator.toString = function(){ return total;}
  return fnGenerator;

})()

console.log('memory leak', String(tick(1)(1)), String(tick(1)(1)))
```

you will get answer n console: 2, 4

see all solutions here : https://github.com/miukki/es5-bind/blob/master/tick.js

Answer (score 0):

There is an internal function object `F` initialized by `fun` when the control comes to the `fun` function expression. `F.[[scope]]` is set to LexicalEnvironment of `addFunction`'s execution context. You can simply consider `LexicalEnvironment` as an object keeping all variables with value in current scope. Here it keeps `num` with it's value. So before `fun` is returned, `num` is set to 6 in `F.[[scope]]`.

Later on when you call by `fun(5)`, what happens behind is `num` is retrieved from `F.[[scope]]` which is 6 and `fun` is actually called by `F.call`

For more on scope chain in JavaScript, there is an awesome post here:
http://hujiale.me/2015/01/31/scope-the-most-important-thing-in-javascript/